# How to validate a list of checkbox through custom jQuery in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a list of checkboxes that i want to validate on client side with jQuery but failing. I have already added unobtrusive and jquery validation plugin to my project.

The Model code is:

```
 [Required]
 public string name { get; set; }

 [SkillValidation(ErrorMessage = "Select at least 3 skills")]
 public List<CheckBox> skills { get; set; }
```

and other model is:

```
public class CheckBox
{
    //Value of checkbox 
    public int Value { get; set; }
    //description of checkbox 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    //whether the checkbox is selected or not
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Explanation - SkillValidation() is the custom attribute which i have created to do server side validation.

The SkillValidation class code is:

```
public class SkillValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<CheckBox> instance = value as List<CheckBox>;
        int count = instance == null ? 0 : (from p in instance
                                            where p.IsChecked == true
                                            select p).Count();
        if (count >= 3)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Explanation: This code will validate user to check at least 3 checkboxes on the server side. I did not inherited this class from **IClientValidatable** interface because i know it wont be possible to do validation from the MVC way (unobtrusive manner).

My View code is:

```
@model demo.MVC.Models.CB
@{
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.skills)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.skills[0].IsChecked, new { id = "csharpSkill" }) C#
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.skills[1].IsChecked, new { id = "aspSkill" }) ASP.NET
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.skills[2].IsChecked, new { id = "jquerySkill" }) jQuery
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.skills[3].IsChecked, new { id = "mvcSkill" }) ASP.NET MVC
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.skills[4].IsChecked, new { id = "razorSkill" }) Razor
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.skills[5].IsChecked, new { id = "htmlSkill" }) HTML
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.skills)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
}

@Scripts.Render("~/jQuery")
@Scripts.Render("~/jQueryValidate")
@Scripts.Render("~/Unobtrusive")
```

Explanation: In the view i have created the text box for name and 6 checkboxes for the skills created with **@Html.CheckBoxFor()**.

Problem: The problem is that If i remove the 6 checkboxes then client side validation works well for the name text box.

If i put 6 checkboxes and press the button then only the server side validation works for **name and checkboxe**.

I want client side validation to work for the 6 checkboxes too so that user has to select 3 checkboxes at least.

How can i achieve it ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot achieve that using MVC's client side validation (by implementing `IClientValidatable` and using `jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js)`. The reason is that client side validation rules are applied to form controls, and you do not (and cannot) create a form control for your `skills` property which is a collection, not a simple value type.

You need to write your own scripts to validate the number of checked checkboxes (and if not valid, make use of the placeholder generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.skills)`

To mimic jquery's 'lazy' validation, initially handle the `.submit()` event, and there after, handle the `.click()` event of the checkboxes.

Modify your 2nd `<td>` element to add an `id` attribute for selecting the checkboxes (see also notes below)

```
<td id="skills">
    .... // your checkboxes
```

and add the following scripts

```
var validateSkillsOnCheck = false; // for lazy validation
var requiredSkills = 3;
var skills = $('#skills input[type="checkbox"]');
var errorMessage = 'Select at least 3 skills';
var errorElement = $('span[data-valmsg-for="skills"]');

// function to validate the required number of skills
function validateSkills() {
    var selectedSkills = skills.filter(':checked').length;
    var isValid = selectedSkills > requiredSkills;
    if (!isValid) {
        errorElement.addClass('field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-valid').text(errorMessage);
    } else {
        errorElement.addClass('field-validation-valid').removeClass('field-validation-error').text('');
    }
    return (isValid);
}

$('form').submit(function () {
    validateSkillsOnCheck = true;
    if (!validateSkills()) {
        return false; // prevent submit
    }
});
$('#skills').on('click', 'input', function () {
    if (validateSkillsOnCheck) {
        validateSkills();
    }
})
```

A few side notes.

1. Tables are for tabular data, not layout and using a `<table>`
   element is not appropriate in your case.
2. Your `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.skills)` is not appropriate (you
   do not have a form control for `skills` so clicking on it does not
   set focus to anything). That should just be a `<span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.skills)</span>` or similar element.
3. You should however be creating labels for each checkbox. Your model has 3 properties including `Text` and `Value` and its not clear what the difference is between them, and in any case, you never include them in the view. I assume your will want to submit at least the `Value` property so you know which skills have been selected

   ```
   <label>
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>m.skills[i].IsChecked)
       <span>@Model.skills[i].Text</span>
   </label>
   @Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.skills[i].Value)
   ```

Comment: Although your jQuery code worked but i have a little problem. Suppose when a user comes to the form and selects - 4 skills but does not puts his name. In that case the client side jQuery should give him the error for name field. This is not happening because the page is getting postback on button click.  Name property is already [Required]. Why it is happening?

Comment: I mean to say the when a user selects the required skills and press the submit button the the application does run the client side validations of other properties at all.

Comment: Your form will not submit and you will get a client side error if the user does not fill in the `name` textbox (and I have already tested that). Are you sure the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files are loaded?

Comment: And not related, but why do you have `HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;` and `HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;` in your view. They are true by default (and should be in your `web.config.cs` file.

Comment: yes jquery validate.js and jquery validate unobrusive.js are loaded. I checked it by removing the whole 6 checkboxes (second td contents) from the view, the validation for name are working on client side. why it is behaving so, is it microsoft bug?

Comment: I use on HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true; and HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true; in your view. I can use in web.config too. I think they were false by default in my vs 2015

Comment: No, there is no bug (and as I noted, I have already tested it and it works fine). I will copy this to a DotNetFiddle later to prove it (busy now but give me 30 min or so)

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GmMXy8). Start by clicking the Save button. Both validation messages appear. Check 3 checkboxes and see the 2nd message disappear (and if you then uncheck one the 2nd error message will be show again. Finally enter a Name and the 1st message will disappear and now click submit to prove the form was submitted.

Comment: thank @stephen i think my solution must be having some problem. I will check it from my end.

Comment: I found out the problem is due to bug in Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation 3.2.3 version. Through Nuget i uninstalled it and installed the 2.0.30506 version. Problem solved now. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142335/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-yogihosting).